# Yet another box-constrained quadratic program

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

I want to consider this simple problem:

$$\min f(x) := x^TQx + qx + r$$
$$s.t.{\ {\ }} -1 \leq x_i \leq 1 {\ {\ }} for {\ {\ }} i = 1,2,3 $$

where

$$ Q =  \begin{pmatrix} 13 & 12 & -2 \\ 12 & 17 & 6 \\  -2 & 6 & 12 \end{pmatrix} , \qquad q = \begin{pmatrix} -22 \\ -13.5 \\ 13 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad r = 1 $$

From here, I can't tell what is the dimension of $x$.

Comment: What does dimension mean here?

Comment: I am assuming $x$ is a matrix. I am not sure if it is $\mathbb{R}^{3{\ } x{\ }n}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n{\ } x{\ }3}$. Both of which doesn't work.

Comment: Somehow $qx$ does not seem right, I guess it should be $q^T x$ (or otherwise define $q$ as a row vector).

Comment: Ah, true. Never saw that. Thanks!